# How can I clone an Ember Data record, including relationships?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've figured out that I can clone an Ember Data record and copy its Attributes, but none of the `belongsTo`/`hasMany` relationships are cloned. Can I do this somehow if I don't know what relationships would be possible, going off of the relationships that exist?

For reference, here is what I've got that will clone an Ember Data record's attributes:

```
var attributeKeys = oldModel.get('constructor.attributes.keys.list');
var newRecord = this.get('store').createRecord(oldModel.constructor.typeKey);
newRecord.setProperties(oldModel.getProperties(attributeKeys));
```

Comment: have you tried using [Ember.copy](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_copy)?

Comment: Have you seen my question? I added an example on how to clone a belongTo item also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20477301/1153884 I am just not sure how to do hasMany items. But I am working on it.

Answer (score 8):

A few improvements to Daniel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22514312) that allows providing overrides, and clears the id for new records, to be safe. Also I prefer not to call `save` within the clone method, but leave it up to the caller.

```
DS.Model.reopen({
    clone: function(overrides) {
        var model = this,
            attrs = model.toJSON(),
            class_type = model.constructor;

        var root = Ember.String.decamelize(class_type.toString().split('.')[1]);

        /*
         * Need to replace the belongsTo association ( id ) with the
         * actual model instance.
         *
         * For example if belongsTo association is project, the
         * json value for project will be:  ( project: "project_id_1" )
         * and this needs to be converted to ( project: [projectInstance] )
         */
        this.eachRelationship(function(key, relationship) {
            if (relationship.kind == 'belongsTo') {
                attrs[key] = model.get(key);
            }
        });

        /*
         * Need to dissociate the new record from the old.
         */
        delete attrs.id;

        /*
         * Apply overrides if provided.
         */
        if (Ember.typeOf(overrides) === 'object') {
            Ember.setProperties(attrs, overrides);
        }

        return this.store.createRecord(root, attrs);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a clone function that I use. Takes care of the belongs to associations.

```
 DS.Model.reopen({
   clone: function() {
    var model = this,
        attrs = model.toJSON(),
        class_type = model.constructor;

    var root = Ember.String.decamelize(class_type.toString().split('.')[1]);

    /**
     * Need to replace the belongsTo association ( id ) with the
     * actual model instance.
     *
     * For example if belongsTo association is project, the
     * json value for project will be:  ( project: "project_id_1" )
     * and this needs to be converted to ( project: [projectInstance] )
     *
     */
    this.eachRelationship(function(key, relationship){
      if (relationship.kind == 'belongsTo') {
        attrs[key] = model.get(key)
      }
    })

    return this.store.createRecord(root, attrs).save();
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an addon called [ember-cli-copyable](https://github.com/lazybensch/ember-cli-copyable) that according to its description:

> Deeply copies your records including their relations. The mixin is smart enough to resolve not loaded relations and is configurable to what should be shallow/deeply copied or excluded entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to clone your **Ember Model with relationships.
working fine.**

Create a Copyable mixin like,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create(Ember.Copyable, {

    copy(deepClone) {
      var model = this, attrs = model.toJSON(), class_type = model.constructor;
      var root = Ember.String.decamelize(class_type.toString().split(':')[1]);

      if(deepClone) {
          this.eachRelationship(function(key, relationship){
              if (relationship.kind == 'belongsTo') {
                  attrs[key] = model.get(key).copy(true);
              } else if(relationship.kind == 'hasMany' && Ember.isArray(attrs[key])) {
                  attrs[key].splice(0);
                  model.get(key).forEach(function(obj) {
                      attrs[key].addObject(obj.copy(true));
                  });
              }
          });
      }
      return this.store.createRecord(root, attrs);
    }
});
```

Add the mixin in your model,

**Note: If you want to clone your child model then, you need to include the mixin in child model as well**

USAGE:

1. With relationship : YOURMODEL.copy(true)
2. Without relationship : YOURMODEL.copy()